# leaf-labelled unordered, rooted binary trees and perfect matchings

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, alternative-proof

While playing with findstat.org, I noticed the following coincidence:

The number of leaf labelled unordered rooted binary trees with $n+1$ leaves $\{1,\dots,n+1\}$, with the leaf labelled $1$ at distance $k$ to the root (http://findstat.org/St001041)

equals

the number of perfect matchings of $\{1,\dots,2n\}$ with $k$ terminal closers (http://findstat.org/St000838).

The distribution of these numbers is given at http://oeis.org/A102625, and I expect that a computational proof would not be very hard to find.

However, I am interested in a bijective proof.

UPDATE: belated, I should mention that I eventually found a bijective proof but only have a rather brief [writeup](https://www.dmg.tuwien.ac.at/rubey/leaf-labelled-trees.pdf) currently.

Comment: You can click on both statistics on "search for distribution" to observe the distribution coincidence yourself.

Comment: Rewriting the formula for the number of matchings of $[2n]$ with $k$ terminal closers as $M_{2(n-k)} \big(\!\binom{k}{2(n-k)}\!\big) k!$ looks helpful, at least for an enumerative proof.

Comment: I am very sorry, but the observation about alignments in the comment I just deleted was completely wrong.

Comment: Sketch of an interpretation of the formula in the comment: construct a leaf labelled tree such that for every node the smallest leaf of the left subtree is smaller than the smallest leaf of the right subtree.  Begin with a path of $k$ left branches and label the leaf $1$. Then attach trees to each of the $k$ right branches.  The relative order of the smallest label in each of these specifies a permutation of $[k]$.  The multisubset specifies which labels appear in which subtree and the splitting of a tree in $M_{2(n-k)}$ into $k$ subtrees.  It remains to understand how the splitting works.

Comment: For a computational proof, see https://mathoverflow.net/q/265727/3032

Comment: Here is a refinement: let $\tau$ be the map from perfect matchings to binary trees detailed in Example 5.2.6 of Enumerative Combinatorics 2, let $d_1(T)$ be the depth of label 1 in the tree $T$, let $i(m)$ be the number of initial openers of the matching $m$ and let $i(T)$ the smallest label whose sister is smaller, minus one.  Note that $i(m) = i(\tau(m))$. 
 Then the distributions of $\big(d_1(\tau(m)), i(m)\big)$ and $\big(i(T), d_1(T)\big)$ are the same.  Put differently, the distribution $\big(d_1(T), i(T)\big)$ is symmetric.

Comment: I think it is really awesome that one can do such automated refinement tests, and indeed find them!

Comment: Here is a generalization: let $\tau$ be the map from set partitions to leaf labelled trees detailed in Erdős and Székely, Applications of antilexicographic order, MathSciNet:1023945, let $d_1(T)$ be the depth of label 1 in the tree $T$ and let $i(p)$ the number of initial openers of the set partition $p$.  Then the distributions of $\big(d_1(\tau(p)),i(p)\big)$ and $\big(i(p),d_1(\tau(p))\big)$ are the same.

Comment: In fact, the generalization to set partitions is rather a sister result than a straightforward generalization: for example, the generating polynomial for set partitions of shape $(3,1,1,1)$ - that is, one block of size 3 and 3 singleton blocks - is no longer symmetric.  Possibly this phenomenon disappears when not allowing singleton blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately got stuck, but I am leaving my work here anyway in case it helps someone else. Happy to delete this if the community feels it is not worthy of being an answer.

---

Your first link references a [book](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec2toc.html) that provides a bijection between the following two sets.

- unordered rooted binary trees with $n+1$ labeled leaves
- matchings of $\{1,\ldots,2n\}$

Note that a binary tree with $n+1$ leaves will have $2n$ non-root nodes, which hints that the above bijection involves labeling of the non-root nodes of a tree. Indeed, this is what the book describes.

I will defer the details to the book, but roughly the bijection is as follows. Take a binary tree with $n+1$ labeled leaves. We will label the remaining non-root nodes with $n+2,\ldots,2n$ in the following way.

- Consider all unlabeled non-root nodes whose two children are both labeled, and label as $n+2$ the one that has a child with the smallest label.
- Repeat this procedure and label the next node as $n+3$, and so on.

Then to convert these node labelings to a matching on $\{1, \ldots, 2n\}$, just take each pair of sibling nodes' labels as a pair in your matching.

Here is an example from the book, when $n=6$. Try starting with only the $7$ leaves labeled, and then complete the labeling for the rest of the non-root nodes.

[image]

Note that one needs to check this is a bijection; I will not do so here.

---

Now, let us consider your original question, which asks for a bijection between the following two sets.

- unordered rooted binary trees with $n+1$ labeled leaves, and leaf "$1$" at distance $k$ from root
- matchings of $\{1, \ldots, 2n\}$ with $k$ terminal closers

Unfortunately, the above bijection does not immediately solve the problem. For example, the matching $(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)$ has one terminal closer, but in the corresponding tree given by the bijection, leaf $1$ is distance $2$ from the root.

Thus, I suspected one can find some intermediate bijection that, when combined with the tree-matching bijection described above, will produce your desired bijection of these last two sets. But I was unsuccessful in actually finding one that worked.

Some closing remarks and possible bijection building-blocks:

- One can consider $k$ initial openers, rather than $k$ terminal closers
- One can consider the depth of some other leaf, rather than leaf $1$
- More generally, one can permute the items in the matching before/after using the tree-matching bijection.
- The tree corresponding to a matching with $k$ terminal closers has a path $\text{root} \to 2n \to (2n-1) \to \cdots \to (2n-k+1)$, and the node $2n-k$ is a sibling of one of these nodes.